# Connection to SQL DB with Cypress

Tags: javascript, sql, npm, database-connection, cypress

I'm trying to connect with SQL db using cypress followed the [NPM guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-sql-server) . All the dependencies are exactly as mentioned but on running this

```
 cy.sqlServer('SELECT Email FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[User] WHERE Name ="test"')
```

I am getting error as below while running.

> CypressError: cy.task('sqlServer:execute') failed with the following error:
>
> TypeError: No connection configuration given.

Although my cypress.json file has got my database connection string.

Cypress.json

```
{
"baseUrl": "myurl",
"db": {
    "userName": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "server": "test\\test",
    "options": {
        "database": "test",
        "encrypt": true,
        "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true
    }
}    
}
```

The below is my plugins/index.js file

```
  const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
  tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
  on('task', tasks);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `cypress.json` and your plugins file?

Comment: @ZachBloomquist - Added in the question.

Answer (score 7):

To anyone looking for how to solve this like I was:

For some reason Cypress(I am using 3.8.2 and I am not sure what version cypress-sql-server author was using) doesn't see the custom property of 'db'.

One method(you can do this many ways) is to just require the cypress config in the plugins file and reference your custom property from there.

To do this just change the plugins/index.js to look like this:

```
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
const dbConfig = require('../../cypress.json');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbConfig.db);
  on('task', tasks);
}
```

Comment: my module.exports has already few tasks, so instead of  `tasks=...; on('task', tasks);` lines I added `    "sqlServer:execute": () => {` 
`      tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbConfig.db);` 
`      on("task", tasks);` 
`      return tasks;` 
`    },` to make it work

Comment: After this how would we call the other db methods in other classes? with the help of sqlServer?

Answer (score 2):

*alternative to cypress-sql-server*

npm i tedious

> cipress.json

```js
    {
"db": {
  "userName": "xxxxx",
  "password": "xxx",
  "server": "xxxxxxxx",
  "options": {
    "database": "",
    "encrypt": true,
    "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true
  }
}
  
}
```

> plugins/index.js

```js
const Tedious = require('tedious');
const dbConfigSQL = require('../../cypress.json');
module.exports = (on) => {
   on('task', {'sqlServer:execute' : (sql) => {
    const connection = new Tedious.Connection(dbConfigSQL.db);
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        connection.on('connect', err => {
          if (err) {
            rej(err);
          }

          const request = new Tedious.Request(sql, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
            return err ? rej(err) : res(rows);
          });

          connection.execSql(request);
        });
      });
    }
  }
  )};
```

> support/command.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('sqlServer', (query) => {
  if (!query) {
    throw new Error('Query must be set');
  }

  cy.task('sqlServer:execute', query).then(response => {
    let result = [];

    const flatten = r => Array.isArray(r) && r.length === 1 ? flatten(r[0]) : r;

    if (response) {
      for (let i in response) {
        result[i] = [];
        for (let c in response[i]) {
          result[i][c] = response[i][c].value;
        }
      }
      result = flatten(result);
    } else {
      result = response;
    }

    return result;
  });
});
```

> integration/example/sqlServer.spec.js

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context('SQL SERVER', () => {
    
  it('SELECT', () => {

    const sql = `SELECT * FROM DATABASE..TABELA where CAMPO = 1`;

    cy.sqlServer(sql).should(res=>{console.log(res)})


  })

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is in `"server": "test\\test"` in your Cypress.json. It should probably something like `"server": "localhost"`,`"server": "localhost\\SQLExpress"` or something along those lines. The value should be the same value that you use in "Connect to Server" dialog in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: The value on server tag is the same value when you connect with management studio.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving the configuration into env in cypress.json:

```
{
  "env": {
    "db": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "sa",
      "password": "xxxx",
      "database": "CollateralSystem",
      "port": 1433
    }
  }
}
```

Then in plugins\index.js:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.env.db);
  on('task', tasks);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You have missed the return statement which you should include as below

```
 module.exports = (on, config) => {
      tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
      on('task', tasks);  
      return tasks
    }
```